# svgPanZoom: how to contain svg within parent element ('outside'-containment)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am asking sth about this svg pan zoom library:
https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom

How do I contain the svg within the area that is panzoomable, such that the user cannot pan the svg completely out of view, such that it's gone?

Similar to how this works **in a different** panzoom library:

(❌ When you press the link, you need to scroll down for outside containment! There is two sections with the same name, the link leads to the first one, the inside containment! ❌)

https://timmywil.com/panzoom/demo/#Containment%20within%20the%20parent

I am talking about this section:

```
Panzoom(elem, { contain: 'outside', startScale: 1.5 })
```

#### My attempt:

I edited this starter template https://bumbu.me/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html as such:

```
window.zoomTiger = svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger', {
  zoomEnabled: true,
  controlIconsEnabled: true,
  fit: true,
  center: true,
  contain: true, // ✅ -> changed this line here
  // viewportSelector: document.getElementById('demo-tiger').querySelector('#g4') // this option will make library to misbehave. Viewport should have no transform attribute
});
```

however it seems that it's not working as I want it to. I am not quite sure what the contain option even means in the svgPanZoom library.

The [@timmywil/panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom) library does this perfectly but I find the [svgPanZoom library](https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom) to be more powerful in general so I want to use it instead. In particular the timmywil-panzoom library struggles with zoom when the user has zoomed in a lot already, see this here:
https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom/issues/643